# Mapping a column value to which dates it has rows of

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, select

I have a table of sign-ins for people who are logging time on different projects and I need to compile a report of which days each project was worked on.

My table looks something like this:

```
id | project | time_in
----------------------------------
1  | 1       | 2014-12-07 05:00:00
2  | 2       | 2014-12-08 06:00:00
3  | 1       | 2014-12-05 14:00:00
4  | 3       | 2014-12-07 08:30:00
5  | 2       | 2014-12-07 12:00:00
6  | 1       | 2014-12-08 05:00:00
7  | 2       | 2014-12-05 06:00:00
8  | 1       | 2014-12-06 14:00:00
9  | 3       | 2014-12-08 08:30:00
10 | 2       | 2014-12-06 12:00:00
```

`time_in` is of type `TIMESTAMP`.

What I need to figure out is, given a date range (e.g. December 5 - 8), which days of the week each project was worked on. I'm totally flexible on the query, i.e. I can generate the query using a loop, and I'm also flexible on how the result set looks, so long as I can parse it to get the information I need. For example, maybe:

```
project | days
-----------------------------------------------------
1       | 2014-12-07,2014-12-08,2014-12-05,2014-12-06
2       | 2014-12-08,2014-12-07,2014-12-05,2014-12-06
3       | 2014-12-07,2014-12-08
```

Or better yet:

```
project | d0 | d1 | d2 | d3
---------------------------
1       | 1  | 1  | 1  | 1
2       | 1  | 1  | 1  | 1
3       | 0  | 0  | 1  | 1
```

I honestly have no idea where to even begin on a query like this, if it's even possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `group_concat` to achieve your initial results:

```
select project, group_concat(date(time_in) order by time_in)
from yourtable
group by project
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9e0472/2)

If you want additional columns, you could use `max` with `case`:

```
select project, 
  max(case when date(time_in) = '2014-12-05' then 1 else 0 end) d0,
  max(case when date(time_in) = '2014-12-06' then 1 else 0 end) d1,
  max(case when date(time_in) = '2014-12-07' then 1 else 0 end) d2,
  max(case when date(time_in) = '2014-12-08' then 1 else 0 end) d3
from yourtable
group by project
```

- [More Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9e0472/3)